# How query variables with part of var in SQLite python

Tags: python, sqlite, select, glob

I should query some variables in SQLite with part of them,like below code
and I need get all numbers in this column that start with 5070 and I use ?*

```py
  Number = 5070
  point = 5
  point_s =25
  result1 = cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM C1 WHERE 
                  point = ?
                  AND point_s = ?
                  AND trackNumber GLOB '5070*' 
                  AND observed LIKE 'A%'
                  order by rowid""", (probeType, probe))
```

with this way get all from column that start with 5070 but when I use ?* for var face with error

```py
  result1 = cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM C1 WHERE 
                  point = ?
                  AND point_s = ?
                  AND trackNumber GLOB ?* 
                  AND observed LIKE 'A%'
                  order by rowid""", (probeType, probe, TrackNumber))
```

but when I use this face an error said **"sqlite3.OperationalError: near "AND": syntax error"**
Is there any way to solve this problem ?

+Also I use LIKE instead of GLOB still didn't work and Also I use % and face same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the asterisk from the SQL and append it to the argument:

```
result1 = cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM C1 WHERE 
                  point = ?
                  AND point_s = ?
                  AND trackNumber GLOB ? 
                  AND observed LIKE 'A%'
                  order by rowid""", (probeType, probe, str(TrackNumber) + "*"))
```

If `TrackNumber` is already a string, the `str(...)` around it isn't necessary.